# How to undo a Heroku Rollback

Tags: heroku

Is it possible to undo a rollback on Heroku?
I have to try something on a live environment, do a test and then get back to the original state (before the rollback). Is Heroku able to do that smoothly or this would lead to problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can roll to whichever release you'd like. Run `heroku releases` to see a history of your deploys then you can select the release you like to 'roll back' to and run `heroku rollback <release id>`. Documentation for this, [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/releases#rollback).

Comment: To clarify: Rolling back on Heroku doesn't throw away old releases. It creates a _new_ release on top of the previous ones. The old ones are still there and are valid targets for rolling back (forward) again.